# Expansion of cell when cell is tapped

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working with the tableview and working well with that. But i stuck at one place where i want to tap the cell and on the tap the cell should expand its height and and the cell below it should move down according to the expanded height. 
The code which i am using is as follows.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    [cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:0]; // unlimited number of lines
    gratitude *grat = [gratitude_list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=grat.gratitude;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Lucida Sans" size:20]];
    return cell;
}  

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    gratindex > -1;

    if (gratindex == indexPath.row) {
        [self collapseSubItemsAtIndex:indexPath];
        gratindex = -1;
    }
    else {

        BOOL shouldCollapse = gratindex > -1;

        if (shouldCollapse) {
            [self collapseSubItemsAtIndex:gratindex];
        }

        gratindex = (shouldCollapse && indexPath.row > gratindex) ? indexPath.row - [[gratitude_list objectAtIndex:gratitude_list] count] : indexPath.row;

        [self expandItemAtIndex:gratitude_list];
    }

     [self.gratitude_tableview endUpdates];


}
- (void)expandItemAtIndex:(int)index
{

     NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
     int insertPos = index + 1;
     for (int i = 0; i < [gratitude_list count]; i++) {
     [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertPos++ inSection:0]];
}
    [self.gratitude_tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
     [self.gratitude_tableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
- (void)collapseSubItemsAtIndex:(int)index {
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i = index + 1; i <= index + [[gratitude_list objectAtIndex:index] count]; i++) {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    }
    [self.gratitude_tableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}
```

Please help me out if  i am using wrong approch please help me out.

Comment: So what is problem?? is it give any error?

Comment: no it is not giving me the error….. it is not giving me the desired output...

Comment: could you show picture like "What you want && what you get"? It may help us to post correct answer..

Comment: k i am adding the image...

Comment: i am not able to uplaod he image due to reputation ….. i simply want to to add the textview with the data below the cell on which i tap …...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312033/expand-collapse-cell-collapse-row-when-other-rows-selected-in-ios/18312651#18312651). If you need any more detailing then you can ask me in comment.

**UPDATED:**
ANd in .h file

```
@interface tableViewDemoViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSIndexPath *selectedCellIndexPath;
    BOOL clickedAgain;
    int heights;
}
```

And in .m file

```
#import "tableViewDemoViewController.h"

@interface tableViewDemoViewController ()

@end

@implementation tableViewDemoViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    clickedAgain = YES;
    heights =0;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 15;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is cell %d",indexPath.row ];

    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    if ([selectedCellIndexPath compare:indexPath] == NSOrderedSame && !clickedAgain)
    {
        heights =40;
        clickedAgain =YES;
    }
    else
    {
        heights =80;
        clickedAgain = NO;

    }

    [tableView beginUpdates];
     selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath;
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(selectedCellIndexPath != nil
       && [selectedCellIndexPath compare:indexPath] == NSOrderedSame )
    {
        return heights;
    }

    return 40;
}  @end
```

Comment: i simply want to to add the textview with the data below the cell on which i tap the cell …… and shift the cell which is after that cell.

Comment: see i am having the table view when i tap my cell its height shoud increase downwards. and cell bellow it should shift accordingly...

Comment: what is lastIndexPath in that??

Comment: lastIndexPath is a member variable.. to save your index of last clicked row.. Just declare it in your .h file..